# refactorizar función rotar

Tags: javascript, array

La **funcion rotar** recibe un **string** y un **numero**, y debe retorna un **nuevo arreglo** con los **elementos rotados**, la cantidad de **veces** como sea el **numero** a la derecha.

```
function rotar(arr, num) {
    let longArr = arr.length
    let long = arr.length - num;
    let newArr = arr.slice(long,longArr)
    let longArr2 = arr.length - arr.length
    let longNewArr2 = arr.length - num
    let newArr2 = arr.slice(longArr2,longNewArr2)
    newArr = newArr.concat(newArr2)
    return newArr;
}

console.log(rotar([1,2,3,4,5],2)); // [4,5,1,2,3]
console.log(rotar([1,2,3,4,5],3)); // [3,4,5,1,2]
```

*como puedo hacer un código mas legible* no tan complejo, ya que apenas estoy iniciando, pero siento que este es algo enredado. Gracias por su ayuda¡

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el metodo
[slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) tambien permite valores negativos por lo que puedes tomar los ultimos 2 pasandole -2

```js
function rotar(arr, num) {
    if (num > arr.length -1) return "error de longitud";
    let long = arr.length - num;
    let newarr = arr.slice(0,long);
    return arr.slice( -num).concat( newarr)
}

console.log(rotar([1,2,3,4,5],2)); // [4,5,1,2,3]
console.log(rotar([1,2,3,4,5],3)); // [3,4,5,1,2]
```